# Programatically change the "Value" of a "Property" in the "Details" section of a Media File in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

In Windows File Explorer you can edit the values in the Details tab of a Media File's properties, but i am looking to do it with command line or Powershell or other scripting, or some other way to automate it.

To be clear, I am referring to the information found in the "Details" tab when you view the file properties, NOT file attributes.

Specifically the values for "Title" and "Comments"

I've tried [wmic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic) but it does not offer those details of the file.

I've tried automating the GUI with AutoIt but hitting too many hurdles and it is too prone to hangups if unattended.

I have searched the web and have not even found a single HINT that this can be done, all posts that had titles that led me to believe it had the answer was either misleading or about file attributes.

Can this be done? or am I just crazy?

EDIT:new info: I tried ffmpeg which works, but the downside is that it has to either re-encode the entire movie or copy it, which takes longer than acceptable for my specific project.
so far automating the GUI with AutoIt is my only viable option.

EDIT: Solution: thanks to @LotPings and @uSlackr for leading me to TagLib-Sharp I now have a method for doing this with Powershell.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638570/powershell-how-to-set-title-in-extended-file-properties) As Windows itself has no idea of Extended File Attributes or meta data - it needs the help of [Shell Extension Handlers](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/shell/handlers)[Property Sheet Handlers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/cc144106(v%3Dvs.85))[Metadata handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb761474(v=VS.85).aspx) which *may* come with APPs for their file types. The property names vary with Win/APP/locales. So NO.

Comment: @LotPings thanks for the info, Microsoft docs always give me a headache, but at least that explains why i couldnt find any info for doing it with command line. that "related" link talks about TagLib#, i may give that a try, looks promising and not too complicated.

Comment: you can do this with Powershell. here is one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104977/powershell-editing-mp3-infos

Comment: @uSlackr that post also leads me to TagLib#, so i guess i will be working with that over the weekend, ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @LotPings and @uSlackr I found [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40839588/10926015) for directly downloading the TagLib-Sharp.dll library and called it directly with help found in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30104977/10926015) resulting in a very basic Powershell script consisting of...

loading the library...

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom( (Resolve-Path ".\taglib\Libraries\taglib-sharp.dll"))
```

and changing the 'Title'

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.mp4 | ForEach-Object { [TagLib.File]::Create($_.FullName) | ForEach-Object { $_.tag.Title = 'noTitleNow' ; $_.Save() } }
```